# Create list (class variable) from class parameters

Tags: python, list, function

How I can put function parameters in class variable, i.e. list ('byte')?
at the moment NameError: name 'self' is not defined error apears

```
class Bit():
def __init__(self, bit1, bit2, bit3, bit4, bit5, bit6, bit7, bit8, number=0):
    self.bit1 = bit1
    self.bit2 = bit2
    self.bit3 = bit3
    self.bit4 = bit4
    self.bit5 = bit5
    self.bit6 = bit6
    self.bit7 = bit7
    self.bit8 = bit8
    self.number = number

byte = [self.bit1, self.bit2, self.bit3, self.bit4, self.bit5, self.bit6, self.bit7, self.bit8]

def converter_integer(self):
    total_value = 0
    for index, element in enumerate(byte):
        if element > 0:
            total_value += 2 ** index
    return total_value
```

Comment: `self` refers to an instance, how would that translate to a class variable? do you really need a class variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```py
Class Bit():
    def __init__(self, number, *bits):
        self.number = number
        self.byte = bits
    
    def converter_integer(self):
        total_value = 0
        for index, element in enumerate(self.byte):
            if element > 0:
                total_value += 2 ** index
        return total_value
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I limit parameters? In this case, function can not accept more than 8 bits

Comment: @Karolis Zimantas You can simply add an `assertion` in the `__init__`like this: `assert len(bits) == 8`. It would raise an `AssertionError` when the length of bits is not equal to 8.